# Chrome считает что jQuery хочет меня ограбить

Tags: javascript, jquery

Захожу я в хром и думаю,почему кнопка модального окна не работает а тут ошибка

```
GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
util.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:56
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Я попытался пойти по ссылку и оказалось что...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берите с GitHub и загружайте локально. У них с SSL-сертификатом проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]